# how to move multiple apps services from one subscription to another subscription in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

we have to Migrate Azure app services from one Subscription to another subscription. how do we move them...? Guess, move operation is not supported for multiple app services to another subscription. how do we migrate multiple app services to another subscription.? Can we backup and restore multiple app services to another subscription...? we tried move operation but that fails for more than one app service.

Comment: You want to move multiple app services at a time?

Comment: `but that fails for more than one app service` What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Does all your  App Services reside in a same resource group ?

Comment: @Harshitha : App services  are in a one resource group while running validation there is an error  it is not supported to move multiple app services from single resource group and if we try to move app service to different resource group and then  move from there it says app service should in the resource group  in which it was created .

Comment: @Harshitha  :not multiple app service at a time one at a time is also okay.

Comment: Ok..will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

> Guess, move operation is not supported for multiple app services to another subscription.

- We have an option to move multiple resources/App Services at a time.
- This is possible only for the resources which are under the same resource group.
- Select the App Services which you want to move.

[image]

[image]

- You can see the option to move (single resource) to another subscription in the Overview of the App Service.

[image]

- You can move the resource only when both the subscriptions have the same `TenantID`.

Even [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json#checklist-before-moving-resources) says the same.

> The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same [Microsoft Entra tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant).

Also refer [Limitation on moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations#move-across-subscriptions) for more details.

- Before moving the resources, check whether you can access the destination Subscription is accessible and you are able to create resources in it.

Comment: Moving multiple resources is supported.but multiple app services from source resource group in source subscription to target resource group in target subscription is not supported. only one app service can be moved from source resource group to target resource group in target subscription. if we try more than one it fails.  Msdoc :"The destination resource group must not have any existing App Service" want to know how multiple app services in one resource group  can be moved to another resource group in target subscription.

Comment: `"The destination resource group must not have any existing App Service"` The error clearly says that the App service with the same name exists in the destination resource group.Cross check the resource group once.

Comment: That is the problem we want to move multiple App services in one resource group in source to a single resource group in target subscription. There are no 2 App services with same name.

Comment: Iam unable to try from my end as I don't have access to other subscription.

Comment: Delete the existing appserices from destination resource and try to move again.

Comment: Requirement is Moving multiple app services from source resource group in one subscription to another subscription into one single resource group. There are no existing app services in target subscription.                              @Harshitha: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Can you please share the screen cap of the error once.